# Alignment image using css selector

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS selector `:before` to put image before text. This is my snippet

But it seems the alignments is a bit off. Text is not vertically aligned with the image.

```css
.resource {
  color: #007f00;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
.resource:before {
 content: '';
    width: 26px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:5px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 19px;
    background-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg");

}
```

```html
<div class="resource">Presentation</div>
```

I have added `margin-top` in `:before` but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to accomplish your goal is to use a `Flexbox` and `align-items: center`. This will align all items vertically centered. You can also remove your `margin-top`:

```css
.resource {
  color: #007f00;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.resource:before {
  content: '';
  width: 26px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="resource">Presentation</div>
```

But it would be interesting to know why you put your image as a `::before` element...

Comment: So am I! But it's the code I had received from the client. I wonder if this flexbox would work in IE.

Comment: Yes it does. https://caniuse.com/#search=align-items

Answer (score 2):

Set `.resource` **display: inline-block;** and remove **margin-top** from `.resource` and `:before` and Add **vertical-align:middle** with **line-height**

```css
.resource {
  color: #007f00;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.resource:before {
 content: '';
    width: 26px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:5px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg");
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="resource">Presentation</div>
```

Comment: It is an approach but this approach does not align items *perfectly* centered. You can see that by inspecting the elements and comparing @ProX's result and yours.

Comment: @Aaron3219 yes by giving line-height and vertical-align:middle to resource it is perfect center.

Comment: No it isn't perfectly centered. Compare both results. The text is 1-2px above the center. Expand the snippets in two tabs and switch between them. You will see the difference and if you inspect it closer you can also see that the text is not perfectly centered.

Comment: Yes... you can see it. That is why I liked @Aaron3219 approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your HTML and CSS as the following, then you can achieve the same result more efficiently:

```css
.resource {
  display: flex;
}

span {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 19px;
}

span img {
  height: 20px;
  width: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resource">
  <span><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg"/></span>
  <span>Presentation</span>
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0sgdfmwr/) is a link to JSFiddle where you can see the result too.